# How to find FormView within GridView EmptyDataTemplate

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView contains Formview like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     OnRowCommand="gv1_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="employeeID"
     DataSourceID="ds">
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
       <asp:FormView ID="fv1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="employeeID" 
                     DataSourceID="ds" DefaultMode="Insert">
           <InsertItemTemplate>
               // insert mode table
           </InsertItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
              //  edit mode table
           </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:FormView>
   </EmptyDataTemplate>

   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
       <HeaderTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" Text="New Record" CommandName="New" />
       </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I want is when the button been clicked, then page displays the EmptyDataTemplate, so in codebehind I try:

```
protected void gv1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    switch(e.CommandName){
        case "New":
            gv1.DataSourceID = null;
            break;
        case "Edit":
            var row = ((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            if (row != null) {
                var fv = row.FindControl("fv1") as FormView;
                fv.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
            }
            gv1.DataSourceID = null;
            break;
    }
}
```

But I stuck in getting FormView, it occurs NullReferenceException error.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Any type of template field must be placed inside <asp:TemplateField> tags. Then in row data bound check for rowtype. If its of empty then find formview using e.row.FindControl method. Generally this template is used when the datasource doesnot contains and row and binding results to 0 row. Then the empty data template is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `EmptyDataTemplate` only shows when you have bound to a data source and there are no records in the source.  So if you have any records, your `EmptyDataTemplate` will never show.  And I don't believe the columns with the command buttons will show when the data source is empty, either, so what you're attempting to do cannot be done in that way.

Some people provide add-record functionality by using the grid footer as a place to add a new row.  Here's a Stack Overflow question and answer (with an example) of how to do it:

[ASP.net GridView not Inserting from Footer Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263891/asp-net-gridview-not-inserting-from-footertemplate?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

`EmptyDataTemplate` is used when datasource returns zero records. It is used for displaying messages such as 'No records' found'. If you want to databind a control use a `Templatefield` & fetch control using `FindControl` on RowDataBoundEvent.